# Syncing a .plist file with iCloud

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, icloud

I am trying to work out how to sync a .plist file I have in the "Application Support" folder in my Sandboxed app for the Mac. I know I could use the iCloud key value store, but there is a limit of 64KB per app, which may or may not be hit depending on how many thing the user adds to the app!

I have read as much of the Apple documentation as possible, but I am still rather confused :(

Has anyone does something similar to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should create a subclass of **`UIDocument`** and use it with ubiquity directories.

There are 2 methods responsible for handling read/write. This one is called when reading:

```
- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

And this one when writing:

```
- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
```

All open/save actions are called automatically, you don't have to do anything. Howewer, there are methods that force open/save. Call this when opening:

```
- (void)openWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler

/* --- EXAMPLE --- */

MyDocument *doc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousFileURL];
[doc openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        // do sth
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}];
```

... and this when saving:

```
- (void)saveToURL:(NSURL *)url forSaveOperation:(UIDocumentSaveOperation)saveOperation completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler

/* --- EXAMPLE --- */

MyDocument *doc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];

[doc saveToURL:[doc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        // do sth
    } else {
        // handle error
    }
}];
```

---

There are many tutorials on the web, here are some examples that I used for learning:

- [Beginning iCloud in iOS 5 Tutorial Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1)
- [Beginning iCloud in iOS 5 Tutorial Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6031/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2)

[UIDocument Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html) may also help.

Comment: That is for iOS if I am not mistaken, can't do that on the Mac :( Most tutorials I have found have been for iOS, hardly anything pertaining to Mac

Comment: So you can do this with `NSDocument`, I think... Take a look at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I did try but it's not as similar to uidocument as I thought it would :/

Comment: initWithFileURL is not available in NSDocument