# How can I use iCloud Sync if I'm not using Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, ios, synchronization, icloud

I've seen a few examples showing how to integrate iCloud with Core Data, but my app uses a handwritten SQLite persistence layer.

Am I just out of luck, or are there straightforward ways to do syncing and conflict resolution over iCloud with a non-Core Data database?

Answer (score 1):

"Straightforward" might not be the first word that comes to mind, but you can definitely use iCloud storage in non-Core Data apps. You'll need to manage your storage engine, conflict resolutions, and data presentation yourself, however; you don't get the "easy" merging and resolution that Core Data gets you.

Read up on the [iCloud Storage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html) guide for detailed info. There's a good checklist a little way down that guides you through setting up document-based storage in your app.

Answer (score 0):

you should check out this stack overflow answer link it iCloud synk but for OSX application basically the same thing. just use .plist files. hope it helps. It helped me on my mac app [OSX app iClound synk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630361/syncing-a-plist-file-with-icloud)

[iCloud tutorial part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6015/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1)

[iCloud tutorial part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/6031/beginning-icloud-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2)